# A student has take eight hours of classes a week he wants to have fewer hours on Friday than on Thursday

Tags: permutations, combinations

> A student has take eight hours of classes a week. He wants to have fewer hours on Friday than on Thursday. In how many ways can he do this?

i am weak in combinations....how to find this?

Comment: Have you tried some systematic case by case analysis? Clearly he can't take four hours Friday. How many ways can he take three? Two? One? None?

Comment: @EthanBolker..he can take ..3 or 2 or 1

Comment: @EthanBolker..only 1

Comment: If he takes $3$ on Friday he must take $5$ or $4$ on Thursday. There are $3$ ways to take $4$ on Thursday - his other class is Monday or Tuesday or Wednesday. So in all, $4$ ways if Friday is $3$. The other Friday possibilities are a little more complicated, but not impossibly difficult. When you're done, post an answer to your own question. (I've no more hints for you.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this student only goes to school Monday through Friday.

Let

$\begin{align*}
m &= \text{hours on Monday} \\
t &= \text{hours on Tuesday} \\
w &= \text{hours on Wednesday} \\
r &= \text{hours on Thursday} \\
f &= \text{hours on Friday}
\end{align*}$

$r$ can be anything from $0$ to $8$.

$f$ can be anything from $0$ to $-|r-4.5|+3.5$ (this was acquired by plotting the maximum value of $f$ given the value of $r$ on a graph and putting an equation to the pattern; this can be and was done by hand). **Note that a summation from $0$ to $\text{[some negative number]}$ is $0$.**

$m$ can be anything from $0$ to $8-r-f$.

$t$ can be anything from $0$ to $8-r-f-m$.

$w$ is uniquely determined: it is $8-r-f-m-t$, so we need not include it in our summation.

And we want to count each scheduling possibility once, so we get

$$\sum_{r=0}^{8} \, \sum_{f=0}^{-|r-4.5|+3.5} \,\, \sum_{m=0}^{8-r-f} \,\, \sum_{t=0}^{8-r-f-m} \,\, 1$$

Evaluating this should give the solution. It's easier than it looks if you remember that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} c = n \cdot c$, where $c$ is a constant or a variable that you're *not* summing over.

Because of the absolute value, I believe you'll have to compute the final summation (which will be in terms of $r$) by hand, but it's only $9$ terms, so it's not that bad.

You'll know that you've done it correctly if your answer is of the form $3^a + 1$ for some integer $a < 10$.